# Want to know about the best framework available for my app

Tags: c#, asp.net, biometrics

I am trying to design a new application which basically aims at providing biometric authentication services. What I want to do is that the app will present the user with an interface where the user can get his eye scanned for authentication. *The most important feature I want to incorporate is that the user need not have a webcam, the app must be able to read the eye from the display device i.e. CRT or LCD screen itself.*

I want info about the best framework available for this. Once successfully tested, I am planning to provide it as a webservice. Any one who will help me will get a royalty from my income.

Comment: Is this a serious question. It is April fools.

Comment: Those interested in this type of thing, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561964/new-asp-showat-attribute-required-inconsistently-in-vs2010-why

Comment: @Bobby Cannon: You have three guesses, and the first two don't count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're want Microsofts new multi-eye monitors.  This is a special version of [Multi-Touch](http://www.informationweek.com/news/windows/operatingsystems/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=208400573') intended for eye validation, much like how [Microsoft Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/) is intended for surface finger interaction.   For example, you can just lay an eye on the table, and the table can sense the eye is there and validate it, using blue-tooth or whatever.  I saw a demo where this guy just shakes his eye *near* the table and it validated him.  I was so cool.  SDK's will be available for Retina, Iris, etc.

I know for a fact that there has not been a lot of work done in this area, but the potential is big.  I wish you luck.

Comment: We'll need to put some security mechanism here as a safeguard against theft of eye. Maybe we can ask the person to get his fingerprint scanned as well. If both the data don't match, then confiscate the eye.

Comment: @vamyip  I would agree that you always want layered security, with eyes as much as anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use (old) monitors with electron tubes (LCD screens are not suited for your purpose). By applying a rectifier for the electric current input, swapping the polarity of the cable set to the electron tube and focussing the electron ray to a radio button on your user interface where the user is required to stare at you can make sure that the ray hits directly his eye and is reflected back to a small canvas you need on your UI (users should look a bit cross-eyed for this purpose). The electron pressure paints the retina layout directly to the canvas and you can read it out as a simple bitmap. No special SDK required.

Comment: Here's a community who has found some insight into this. Maybe this will help me clarify the problem further.
http://sum.mx/7wht23

Comment: +1 that is some fantastic engineering.  I had a co-worker who rigged up something like that for sound, but the results weren't what we wanted.  I can see how it would work better for video.

Answer (score 1):

You might try Apple's new iEye. This fantastic, magical add-on to the iPad rests on the eye, and is operated via a single easy-to-use button at the bottom of the device. Unfortunately, it only works with the iPad, and the SDK is proprietary.

Comment: +1, great option.  I should have mentioned it.  I discounted it because he's using .net tags and programming for the iEye requires using objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get you.
How do you propose the image of the eye is collected without some kind of image capture device.
A bog standard 'display device' is an 'output device' as opposed to an 'input device' - this means there would be no signal.

Are you talking mobile phone apps, custom manufacture eye scanning devices, desktop pc's?
please elaborate.

---

aaah Patrick Karcher - has the correct answer. plus one for that - i should have been more prepared for coming to stackoverflow on april fool's day.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting images from devices without using encoders and drivers, have a look at [TWAIN](http://www.twain.org/) (Technology Without Any Interface). and it's [faq](http://www.twain.org/faqs.shtm#What%20is%20a%20GUID).

*The most important feature I want to incorporate is that the user need not have a webcam, the app must be able to read the eye from the display device i.e. CRT or LCD screen itself.*

are you sure it's possible with the current CRT and LCD technologies? i think you have to have a reading device.

more info from TWAIN.org:

> The TWAIN initiative was originally launched in 1992 by leading industry vendors who recognized a need for a standard software protocol and applications programming interface (API) that regulates communication between software applications and imaging devices (the source of the data). TWAIN defines that standard. The three key elements in TWAIN are the application software, the Source Manager software and the Data Source software. The application uses the TWAIN toolkit which is shipped for free.

good lucks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an April Fools, but... Actually, if you remove the condition about the fact that it must come from a CRT or LCD screen it might be possible to do it without image capture device attached to their computer.

Possibly using their facebook username and some red-eye photos of them (reflection of the flash off the back of the retina) + a lot of luck and R+D.
Authentication then might simply come from some way of proving that you are the person in the photo.